# Overshoot and undershoot on clock signal missing in high frequency(HyperLynx)

Tags: simulation, signal-integrity, high-speed

I'm using it for my work in Hyperlynx SI to test high-speed signals.
This is a general question but I read somewhere that the simulation in high freq could make a problem to identify some peaks in signals, and this is true in my case.
When I tested the signals in 250Mhz oscillator the signals look good without overshoots and undershoots,
and in 25Mhz I saw the overshoots and undershoots like this:

[image: with 25Mhz testing]

I want to know why it happens?
what are the physical explanations for this phenomenon?
Thanks!

Comment: You should show the equivalent diagram at 250 MHz side by side with the original. You should **also** show a version of the 25 MHz diagram focussed at one edge so the overshoot can be examined.

Comment: The real question is how the band limiting occurs in the 25MHz simulation. Plot the step response of that bandwidth limiter and you'll likely have your answer.